# How to fill black color in an image drawn by joining segments?

Tags: r, colors, plot

How to fill in color in an area of image drawn by joining segments.

```
plot.new()
R<-.8
r<-.2
angle<-45
angle1<-45*0.0174532925
angle2<-(angle-15)*0.0174532925
angle3<-(angle+15)*0.0174532925
xpos<-R*cos(angle1)
ypos<-R*sin(angle1)
x1<-r*cos(angle2)
y1<-r*sin(angle2)
x2<-r*cos(angle3)
y2<-r*sin(angle3)
x<-c(0,x1,xpos,x2,0)
y<-c(0,y1,ypos,y2,0)


segments(0,0,x1,y1,lwd=4)
segments(0,0,x2,y2,lwd=4)
segments(x1,y1,xpos,ypos,lwd=4)
segments(x2,y2,xpos,ypos,lwd=4)
```

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 7):

```
polygon(c(0,x1, xpos, x2), c(0, y1, ypos, y2), border="red", col="black", lwd=4)
```

[image]

When using `segments` you could also input all coordinates at the same time, like this

```
segments(c(0,0,x1,x2), c(0, 0, y1, y2), c(x1,x2,xpos,xpos), c(y1,y2,ypos,ypos))
```

Comment: i don't want to use polygon. As this image is part of another image where i don't want to use polygon. Pls suggest me, how can i fill it.

Comment: You could use `image` to plot the area as a bitmap, then overlay the segments to get the contour (which would mask the jagged edges of `image`). It's a peculiar solution though. How come you don't want to use `polygon` but think `segments` is ok? They both plot the same kind of vector graphics.